# Why is my code returning "name 'Button' is not defined"?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

my code is giving me this error and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's telling me "NameError: name 'Button' is not defined." In Tkinter I thought Button was supposed to add a button?

```
import Tkinter

gameConsole = Tkinter.Tk()
#code to add widgets will go below

#creates the "number 1" Button
b1 = Button(win,text="One")

gameConsole.wm_title("Console")
gameConsole.mainloop()
```

Comment: Button is a part of `TKinter` namespace. Use `TKinter.Button(...)`. Keep in mind that for new code bases recommended interpreter version is Python 3. Python 2 support ends in 2020.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few options available to source the namespace:

- `from Tkinter import Button` Import the specific class.
- `import Tkinter` -> `b1 = Tkinter.Button(win,text="One")` Specify the the namespace inline.
- `from Tkinter import *` Imports everything from the module.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
import Tkinter
b1 = Tkinter.Button(win,text="One")
```

or

```
from Tkinter import Button
b1 = Button(win,text="One")
```